# Unwanted glowing line where particles intersect with the particle emitter

Tags: particles, reflection

I am working on a Project and I got a problem with my particle system. I use planes to generate lots of foliage for my background. There is a reflection where the plane intesects with the Underground/emitter and i have no idea how i can remove it.

I was searching for a fix but i couldnt find one so far. Maybe i just couldnt find the right  term.

I added a picture of the scene and hope you can help me. Thank you

[image: Blender scene]

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a plane under the ground to block the light from the hdri worked to fix it. But why did this happen in the first place? Light shouldnt be able to pass through intersecting objects.